# 7z command line = 7-Zip "Extract to"

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I have a dmg "winzipmacedition40.dmg". I'm trying to extract dmg from Windows 7. How do do the "extract to" method via the command line?

#### Result 1

Using right click file -> *7-Zip* -> *Extract to "winzipmacedition40/"*

[image]

#### Result 2

Using the command line:

```
C:\Tes> 7z x winzipmacedition40.dmg -owinziptes

7-Zip 9.13 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-04-15

Processing archive: winzipmacedition40.dmg

Extracting  0.ddm
Extracting  1.Apple_partition_map
Extracting  2.hfs

Everything is Ok

Files: 3
Size:       38797312
Compressed: 11842778
```

[image]

How do I get the same result from the command line as the GUI interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the extract command again over the 2.hfs file,

```
$ 7z x file.dmg -oOUTFOLDER

$ cd OUTFOLDER

$ 7z x 2.hfs

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: 2.hfs

Extracting  WinZip
Extracting  WinZip/.background
Extracting  WinZip/.DS_Store
Extracting  WinZip/.HFS+ Private Directory Data
Extracting  WinZip/.Trashes
Extracting  WinZip/Applications
Extracting  WinZip/WinZip.app
Extracting  WinZip/[]
Extracting  WinZip/.background/backgroundImage.tiff
...
```

Comment: thanks Rabin, could I extract directly 2.hfs file without extract .dmg first?

Comment: not really, but you can try and use a tool which support outputting the file to stdout and pipe that to another round of extraction. or you can wrap it all in single batch/shell script.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x C:\Users\Michael\Documents\sample1\sample1.zip -oC:\Users\Michael\Documents\sample2\
```

So use it in this format:

[absolute path to 7z.exe (not 7zFM.exe)] x (indicates extract with directory structure intact, as opposed to e) [path to zip to extract] -o[folder to extract it to]

Comment: Which is very similar to result two, so check permissions and verify the contents of the zip